# What's the length of the access_token string?

Tags: oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I store the access token received from Soundcloud in a database and would therefore like to know what the maximum  length of the string is. There's a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408945/what-is-the-length-of-the-access-token-in-facebook-oauth2) concerning Facebook. Does the same (1) apply to Soundcloud?

And is the length guaranteed to stay the same in the future or could it change?

*(1) Maximum length is 255 characters there*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI - The maximum length is left undefined by the OAuth 2.0 specification.  So, if the Facebook maximum length did apply, it would be out of coincidence or because the Facebook implementation was referenced by the Soundcloud folks.  Thus you'll need an answer from Soundcloud.

I'd suggest using a larger variable-length column for this info, just in case.  There may be some performance degradation with you database, but I would suspect that would be minimal because of the way you'd reference this data (likely based off user ID in an index) and because you'll likely only be returning a single row at a time.