# Best field type for storing Facebook Access Token

Tags: mysql, facebook-graph-api, database-design, facebook-access-token

Regarding to [this answer to a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16365828/1308905) a Facebook representative is making me a bit confused. He actually says, that there should be no upper limit on the length on the field storing a Facebook Access Token.

This leaves me behind with one question: What is the best MySQL field type for storing a facebook access token then? Is it TEXT? Or is VARCHAR(2048) better, even though it still has a maximum length?

Hope there is some bright minds, that can help me :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that answer it's clear that varchar(2048) will be ok for a while. What is the extra work required by your application to store as a character large object or TEXT. If it is significant then implement as varchar(2048) for now and add this as a possible risk/bugfix for the future, if it is trivial then use TEXT.