# extracting access token out of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string which and I need to get the access token out of this string .However we also need to confirm if access token is there or not .

The string is as followed .

```
      ?utm_source=xyz&utm_medium=xyza&utm_campaign=xyzb&access_token=abybsjw16373vdgw
```

I need to get the access token out of this using javascript.
I would like to understand as how people approach such problems .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you get just this string or a full url ?

Answer (score 4):

we can also do this like

```js
let str="?utm_source=xyz&utm_medium=xyza&utm_campaign=xyzb&access_token=abybsjw16373vdgw"

       let tokenIsPresent=str.search("access_token")
       if(tokenIsPresent !=-1){
       let token= str.slice(tokenIsPresent+13)
        console.log(token)}
        else{console.log("token is not present")}
```

we can find access_token by string.search which will return starting position of our search string ie "50" here
and then we have to add the length of our search ie "access_token=" which is 13 
then we have to slice it by 50+13

Comment: What if the `access_token` length will change? this is generated on backend side so we cannot guarantee that the length will be the same e.g. you can take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408945/what-is-the-length-of-the-access-token-in-facebook-oauth2

You can e.g. slice to the end of the string, but we are still not sure if the parameters orders will be the same. We can get index of `access_token`, check if we can find any `&` characters and slice till the `&` and if not found, slice til the end

Comment: whatever the length and parameter order, if we got "access_token" at last it will work regardless of tokens length

Comment: If the access token length will change, to e.g. 14, and you will slice 13 characters you will miss one char at the end

Comment: did you asking about "access_token" as a key or its value eg "abybsjw16373vdgw", here access_token=abybsjw16373vdgw, its value should change every time ie "abybsjw16373vdgw" and key ie "access_token" it will remain as it is

Comment: Yes `access_token` will be the same :) I think the question is how to get value of the access_token

Comment: and we are getting it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
const str = "?utm_source=xyz&utm_medium=xyza&utm_campaign=xyzb&access_token=abybsjw16373vdgw "
const accessParts = str.match('access_token=.*$')[0].split("=")

console.log(accessParts) // ["access_token", "abybsjw16373vdgw "]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let token='';
if(window.location.href.split('access_token').length>0){
    token=window.location.href.split('access_token')[1].split('&').join(''); 
}
if(!token){
    console.log('token is missing');
}
```